# Why is Ansible not recognizing pywinrm install

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ansible, winrm

I've installed python3.8, ansible, and pywinrm. But when I run the dependency checker, it's not finding winrm even though it's in a python system path

```
[root@serverx:/etc]$ ansible -m python_requirements_info -a dependencies=winrm localhost
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "mismatched": {},
    "not_found": [
        "winrm"
    ],
    "python": "/usr/bin/python3.8",
    "python_system_path": [
        "/tmp/ansible_python_requirements_info_payload_54ltpfcm/ansible_python_requirements_info_payload.zip",
        "/usr/lib64/python38.zip",
        "/usr/lib64/python3.8",
        "/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload",
        "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
        "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
        "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
        "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
    ],
    "python_version": "3.8.12 (default, May 10 2022, 23:46:40) \n[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10)]",
    "python_version_info": {
        "major": 3,
        "micro": 12,
        "minor": 8,
        "releaselevel": "final",
        "serial": 0
    },
    "valid": {}
}
```

```
[root@serverx:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages]$ ll
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root  4096 Jul  1 13:56 ansible
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   126 Jul  1 13:57 ansible-6.0.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 47 root root  4096 Jul  1 13:57 ansible_collections
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   126 Jul  1 13:56 ansible_core-2.13.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   101 Jul  1 13:56 ansible_test
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   112 Jul  1 14:05 certifi
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 14:05 certifi-2022.6.15.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   212 Jul  1 14:05 charset_normalizer
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   126 Jul  1 14:05 charset_normalizer-2.1.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   190 Jul  1 14:05 idna
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   105 Jul  1 14:05 idna-3.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   278 Jul  1 14:05 ntlm_auth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 14:05 ntlm_auth-1.5.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   255 Jul  1 13:56 packaging
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   143 Jul  1 13:56 packaging-21.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    64 Jul  1 14:05 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   271 Jul  1 13:56 pycparser
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 13:56 pycparser-2.21.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   233 Jul  1 13:56 pyparsing
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    81 Jul  1 13:56 pyparsing-3.0.9.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 14:05 pywinrm-0.4.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Jul  1 14:05 requests
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 14:05 requests-2.28.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    68 Jul  1 14:05 requests_ntlm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   131 Jul  1 14:05 requests_ntlm-1.1.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   254 Jul  1 13:56 resolvelib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 13:56 resolvelib-0.8.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 14:05 six-1.16.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 34549 Jul  1 14:05 six.py
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   291 Jul  1 14:05 urllib3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   106 Jul  1 14:05 urllib3-1.26.9.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   152 Jul  1 14:05 winrm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   102 Jul  1 14:05 xmltodict-0.13.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 19094 Jul  1 14:05 xmltodict.py
```

Does this have to do with virtual environments or maybe I need to specify in ansible where to find that? Everything was installed with root privileges.
Thanks

Rocky Linux 8.6, Python 3.8.12, Ansible 2.13.1

Comment: Please [edit your question](/posts/72873069/edit) and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. Turns out i was missing pykerberos (after an update...).

This link gave for me my solution:

https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/mbTSp4Ijd1c

Had to install the python38-devel and after that i had to install kerberos with "pip3.8 install pykerberos"